# How can I get the web application assembly in ASP.NET without Global.asax?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to dynamically get the assembly for the currently executing web application from any code referenced by that application and executed in the same AppDomain.

I want exactly what this question asks: [Get web application assembly name, regardless of current executing assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463284/get-web-application-assembly-name-regardless-of-current-executing-assembly)

However, all replies in that question use the `Global.asax` file to get the web app assembly. That doesn't work if the application doesn't have a global.asax file, since in this case the type returned is `HttpApplication`, which is in the `System.Web` assembly.

One way I thought about going is to filter the assemblies in the current AppDomain by something, but I don't know what this something could be. Is there any difference between the assembly of the web app and another normal DLL? I know that the projects in Visual Studio have a GUID to signify the type of project (ASP.NET Web App, class library, MVC app, etc.) Is this info somehow present in the compiled assembly?

Another approach could be to use the `ApplicationHost` from the `System.Web.Hosting` namespace, but that only has static data and nothing about assemblies.

A third approach would be to include a type in the web app project and use that type, but for that my code which needs to get the web assembly name needs a reference to that type (and that would be a circular reference).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As a very ugly hack, you could find an ASPX file in the app, then get the assembly containing its compiled type:

```
var filePath = Directory.EnumerateFiles(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "*.aspx")
                        .FirstOrDefault();
var assembly = BuildManger.GetCompiledType(filePath).Assembly;
```

If there aren't any ASPX files, you could try ASHX or ASMX or CSHTML.

This will not work correctly for a web site project, where each file gets its own assembly.

Comment: This throws an exception, because the path to the ASPX file is relative, and it expects virtual. When I changed it to `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath`, the returned path is `null`

Comment: I replaced what you suggested with `BuildManager.GetCompiledType("~/Default.aspx").Assembly;`, however it returns a new assembly. GetCompiledType() compiles what you pass to it on demand and creates a new temporary assembly for it, so it doesn't use the web application assembly.

Comment: @Slavo: Hmm... What kind of application is it? I'm trying to figure out how to get a type from it.

Comment: It is a normal ASP.NET app, but the code which I want to get the assembly name with runs in a separate class library project, which is referenced by the web application project.